# Продвинутые инструменты для работы с JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ide

Добрый день!

Имеется очень большой проект, десятки ато и сотни тысяч строк кода (PHP, JS, HTML).
Среди прочих, в проекте подключен JS [компонент для рисования диаграмм](http://www.bryntum.com/), мне необходимо внести небольшие изменения в этом компоненте, посоветуйте пожалуйста как (С помощью каких программ, OS Linux) лучше находить места объявлений переменных, функций итд.

Сейчас работаю в Netbeans, но он к сожалению не справляется, быстрый переход (CTRL+правый клик мыши) либо не срабатывает вовсе, либо выдает кучу не имеющих отношения к делу ссылок. Аналогично и поиск по проекту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebStorm, PhpStorm. Для JS лучше WebStorm не найти! Вроде он и для линукса есть.